Synthesis of monostearate glycerol citrate
Can you tell me about the methodology of synthesis of monostearate glycerol citrate, which is used in food industry. I have problems with this synthesis, because when I attempted this, I received polymers (polyester polymers with glycerol citrate).

And why do you want to synthesize this? What is the purpose?

Well, without right approach you're bound to esterify too much. Protective groups are likely needed.

What procedure you have been using to synthesize monostearate glycerol citrate?
